# How can I wrap multiple elements in a wrapper with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that's wrapping one element just fine:

```
$('.brandModelWrapperGroup').each(function(){
   var divs = $(this).find(".brandModelWrapper")
   for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=brandModelLineCount) {
     divs.slice(i, i+brandModelLineCount).wrapAll("<section class='brandModelLineWrapper'></section>")
   }
})
```

But I need it to wrap not just `.brandModelWrapper`, but also `.brandModelView`, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use comma separated multiple selector:

```
var divs = $(this).find(".brandModelWrapper").add($(this).find(".brandModelView"));
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it adds the `brandModelWrapper` first and then, for what's left in the `brandModelLineCount` is devoted to `brandModelView`. If I double the `brandModelLineCount` variable, it still does the same thing. I need for every one `brandModelWrapper` there's one `brandModelView`.

Comment: This wraps them in two different `.brandModelLineWrapper`

Comment: offcourse it will. do you want them to be added in same section where brandelmodelwrapper ends

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want :) Sorry if I didn't explain it clear enough

Comment: Then use the same approach except dom object will be `$(this).find(".brandModelWrapper").add($(this).find(".brandModelView"));`

Comment: Sadly, that does the same as if I added it like so `$(this).find(".brandModelWrapper, .brandModelView")` - doesn't add for every one `brandModelWrapper` one `brandModelView` :(